# Dual boot on mac with osx system drive encrypted by file vault?

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, macbook, macosx

I have macbook pro and the system drive is encrypted by filevault.

I would like to cut a chunk from that system drive for Ubuntu.

How should I proceed?
Does encryption need to be removed first and then just follow any tutorial or?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you can leave it as it, with filevault active on the Mac partition. However, the Ubuntu partition will not benefit from this encryption, as it's a Mac software-level encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to remove the encryption.  Just open up Disk Utility, select your primary drive(the drive, not a partition), click the 'Partition' tab and you should be able to carve out a chunk of the drive by resizing the rectangle representing your disk space. Then you can use Bootcamp(available in the App store) to make your machine multi-OS.

Comment: How would "Boot Camp" help installing Linux? Boot Camp is meant to ease the installation of Windows but it won't help you installing Linux.